# Fantasy TV mini series that I cannot remember

Tags: story-identification

This is officially my new favourite website.  You helped me find an obscure TV show based on half remembered babies in Biker gear in under 5 minutes!  Truly fantastic.

Here is another puzzler, now in the fantasy genre.

Here's the list of remembered elements:

1. It was a live action miniseries from somewhere in the mid-90s
2. It featured a boy in a coma (something to do with tissue build-up somewhere in his head)
3. The boy was also in a Middle Ages fantasy world.
4. I remember a red flag with three white diamonds on it.
5. There was a young girl (possibly the boy's little sister) who was slowly developing scales (maybe turning into a dragon?)
6. I recall that other children who were in a coma were also in this fantasy world.

That is everything that I can remember off the top of my head.

Answer (score 5):

Could it be *[The Odyssey](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/TheOdyssey)*? The time period fits, and it features a boy in a coma who was transported to another world.

> In the series pilot, 11-year-old Jay tries to join a tree-fort club, led by the tough Keith. As per the prearranged agreement, Jay has brought something of value to contribute to the club: a telescope that belonged to his father (who has been missing several years and is presumed dead). However, Keith double-crosses Jay and takes the telescope, denying him admission into the club. Jay tries to retrieve the telescope with the help of his physically disabled friend Donna, who uses a crutch and a leg brace in order to walk. Jay falls from the tree-fort, however, striking his head against a rock and lapsing into a coma.
>
> In the coma, Jay finds himself in a fantasy world called Downworld where no one reaches the age of 16. Not having heard of adults, the children here have shaped society in their own ways, forming mostly tribal clans in the form of Clubs, such as the Pool Club and the Library Club. The biggest and most powerful Club, however, is the Tower, a brutal despotic police state run by the oldest kids, with Brad as the absolute ruler because he is 15, and "knows everything". Jay, not knowing how he has got here and aided by his friends Alpha and Flash (who are identical to Donna and Keith), embarks on a journey to return home — a place he can't remember. The journey becomes a quest to find his long-lost father, whose name happens to be Brad, who fell overboard from a small boat into a lake while they were on a fishing trip together and has not been seen since.

### Opening Credits

Comment: This does not look familiar but I will research the Odyssey further to see if it's the thing.  I recall a purely sword and sorcery style fantasy world and a slightly darker tone, but these may very well be the effects of the fog of time on my mind.

Comment: Having viewed a couple of episodes, I can say that this is not the show I am looking for.  The fantasy world in Odyssey has a post apocalyptic vibe, whereas the show I am looking for had a traditional sword and sorcery vibe.  It may have also had an older target audience.